# Analysis finds private API usage although I've changed that code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, build, code-analysis

My app was rejected after App Store review for using the private method `-[UIImage initWithData:cache:]`, but this is my code :

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[details image]]];
picture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

An earlier version of the app I submitted *did* contain an `initWithData:cache:` call, but I removed this before resubmitting. Is it possible I need to clean the build? Is the build somehow "remembering" the old code?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59625-initwithdata-cache-not-permissible-apple.html

Comment: `-initWithData:` is allowed; `-initWithData:cache:` is forbidden. You (or some third party code in your project) is using the latter.

Comment: While this question is off topic, I suggest emailing the review team if you feel that they are incorrect. If the review team is correct, find a different way to accomplish this functionality or ditch it.

Comment: @Moshe - I disagree that this is off topic.  It's a code-related problem (a method somewhere tripping Apple's analyzer) and could have a programming-related solution.  While it does involve the review process, there's a programming component to this.

Comment: @Brad: Only Apple can answer this question with any certainty. So if it's not off-topic, then it is almost certainly too localized.

Comment: @Robert - I'm not so sure.  In this case, a particular method has been identified by Apple's review as being private, and the developer is trying to track down where this usage could come from.  A means of finding this problematic method using a command-line Objective-C developer tool is described in the comments on the answer below.  Even if it's a misdiagnosis by Apple, an answer that provides proof of a missing method is what's needed, which seems to be a programming issue, not a policy one.

Comment: @Kara: Please do not add the [appstore-approval] tag to questions. Questions about app store approval are off-topic for Stack Overflow, as noted in the [information page for the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/appstore-approval/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions you used in that snippet have public documentation, so it would be worth complaining to Apple and demanding clarification. Here are the links to the documentation for each of those, BTW:

1. [NSURL URLWithString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL)
2. [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSData)
3. [UIImage initWithData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Note that Apple's message refers to the "initWithData:cache:", however, the snippet you provided refers to "initWithData:". Are you sure that the code you've provided is what was referred to by Apple?

Comment: I think it's more likely the OP is not showing the right code snippet here.

Comment: Good point... I've asked the OP at the end if he is sure that Apple was referring specifically to the snippet in question. In any case, the problem is definitely not the code that the OP provided.

Comment: Thanks. I've done a search in my project for the word "Cache" and the above line is the only search result returned.

Comment: It might be in a framework you're using. Apple will statically analyze the code, so that process is totally automatic. I've never heard of it flagging false positives, but never say never...

Comment: Thanks. The only non Apple framework is AdMob. How can I search a framework for a keyword ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco, you might be able to use "nm" to dump the list of symbols in the library (you would go into the ".framework" folder, and then run "nm" on the "AdMob" library file).

Answer (score 0):

(Copied out from an edit to the question by the OP.)

I resolved this by creating a completely new project and copying files across from old project. It looks like something was ghosting from when the project did contain the `initWithData:cache:` method.